# Idiomatic way to parse a File in Scala

Tags: scala, idioms

I am parsing a file in Scala, I have two kinds of files to read:

A set of train sentences, with this form:

```
String\tString\tInt
String\tString\tInt
// ...
String\tString\tInt
```

And a set of test sentences, with this form:

```
String\tString\tString\tInt
String\tString\tString\tInt
// ...
String\tString\tString\tInt
```

So far I've used `Either` to differentiate between the to kinds of formats:

```
  def readDataSet(file: String): Option[Vector[LabeledSentence]] = {

  def getSentenceType(s: Array[String]) = s.length match {
    case 3 => Left((s(0), s(1), s(2).toInt))
    case 4 => Right((s(0), s(1), s(2), s(3).toInt))
    case _ => Right(("EOS", "EOS", "EOS", -1))
  }

    val filePath = getClass.getResource(file).getPath

    Manage(Source.fromFile(filePath)) { source =>

      val parsedTuples = source getLines() map (s => s.split("\t"))

      // ..........

      // Got throught each token in the file and construct a sentence
      for (s <- parsedTuples) {
        getSentenceType(s) match {
          // When reaching the end of the sentence, save it
          case Right(("EOS", "EOS", "EOS", -1)) =>
            sentences += new LabeledSentence(lex.result(), po.result(), dep.result())
            lex.clear()
            po.clear()
            dep.clear()
          //            if (isTrain) gold.clear()
          case Left(x) =>
            lex += x._1
            po += x._2
            dep += x._3
          case Right(x) =>
            lex += x._1
            po += x._2
            gold += x._3
            dep += x._4
        }
      }
      Some(sentences.result())
    }
  }
```

Is there a better/idiomatic way of simplify this code?

I have removed some part of the code not important for this purpose, If you want to see the complete code, [check my github page](https://github.com/algui91/grado_informatica_TFG_NaturalLanguageProcessing/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/elbauldelprogramador/nlp/utils/DataParser.scala)

**UPDATE**: Following *Dima's* advice, I've simplified my code using a *Monoid*, here is the result:

```
val parsedTuples = source
    .getLines()
    .map(s => s.split("\t"))
    .map {
      case Array(a, b, c, d) => Tokens(a, b, c, d.toInt)
      case Array(a, b, d) => Tokens(a, b, "", d.toInt)
      case _ => Tokens() // Read end of sentence
    }.foldLeft((Tokens(), Vector.empty[LabeledSentence])) {
    // When reading an end of sentence, create a new Labeled sentence with tokens
    case ((z, l), t) if t.isEmpty => (Tokens(), l :+ LabeledSentence(z))
    // Accumulate tokens of the sentence
    case ((z, l), t) => (z append(z, t), l)
  }._2
```

Comment: Some kind of combinator parser, e.g. https://github.com/tpolecat/atto or http://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/

Comment: @Reactormonk, Thanks, I'll take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `Either`. Just always use a 4-tuple:

```
  source
    .getLines
    .map(_.split("\\t"))
    .map {
      case Array(a, b, c, d) => Some(a, b, c, d.toInt)
      case Array(a, b, d) => Some(a, b, "", d.toInt)
      case _ => None
    }.foldLelft((List.empty[LabeledSentence], List[String].empty, List.empty[String], List.empty[String], List.empty[Int])) {
      case ((l, lex, po, gold, dep), None) =>
         (new LabeledSentence(lex.reverse, po.reverse, fold.reverse, dep.reverse)::l, List(), List(), List(), List())
      case ((l, lex, po, gold, dep), Some((a, b, c, d))) => 
         (l, a::lex, b::po, c::gold, d::dep)
   }._1._1.reverse
```

You could make the last step a lot more elegant, if you rethought your approach to the `lex, po, gold, dep` stuff (make it a case class and/or combine with the `LabeledSentence` perhaps?).

And also, you gotta cut down on using mutable containers, it makes it a lot harder to understand what's going on. This is not java ...

Comment: How could I do the second? Just yesterday learnt what Monads are, but right now it seems far too complicated for me.

Comment: The second? Sorry, I edited my answer while you were typing your comment, I think, and now I don't remember what it could be referring to :)

Comment: `This is not java` yes.. I have a lot of issues in github to make all the code possible immutable, but right not it is difficult for me

Comment: I referred about using Monoids

Comment: Oh, Monoid is just a class that has a `.zero` and a `.plus`. For example, `Int` is a monoid. You can define custom monoids in scala, and then, you could just do `parsedTuples.sum(LabeledSentenceMonoid)` ... Don't worry about it yet, perhaps, it's a bit too early :)

Comment: Well, I will do the case class then, and refining the code bit by bit as I  am learning. Thanks!

Comment: What do you think about my update? It is more idiomatic?